# How to adjust layout pan on soft keyboard up

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-textinputlayout

I'm using a `TextIpnutLayout` that holds an `EditText`.
When I'm showing the keyboard the main layout raises until its bottom is aligned with the keyboard (Which `android:adjustPan` suppose to do), but its over the `TextInputLayout`'s error strip, so it does not show.

Is there a way to make the keyboard aligned to the layout?

Comment: have you tried "adjustResize"?

Comment: @KuldeepKulkarni, Yes. But i cant use it because i have a button that gets over the edittext.